# Find and identify multiple display devices (monitors) using Python

Tags: python, windows, screen, monitor, multiple-monitors

I would like to write a Python program that automatically finds and identifies multiple display devices connected to my computer (Windows). Further I would also like to programmatically start a display session (for example a slide show) in one of those devices. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thank you,

Indranil.

Here are links to some related questions (not the exact question):

1. [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)
2. [How to query NATIVE hardware resolution of primary monitor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322153/how-to-query-native-hardware-resolution-of-primary-monitor-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

```
import wmi
obj = wmi.WMI().Win32_PnPEntity(ConfigManagerErrorCode=0)

displays = [x for x in obj if 'DISPLAY' in str(x)]

for item in displays:
   print item
```

It gives all connected monitor details.